# How to create a shared library object on linux x64 which internally uses C++ exceptions and can run on older platforms?

Tags: c++, linux, exception, shared, platform

How can a C++ based shared library, which internally uses C++ exceptions (no exceptions crossing .so boundaries), be created on one Linux x64 (e.g. Red Hat 7.x) platform be created in such a way it can be run on other platforms which are ABI compatible to the shared library (e.g. Red Hat 5.x or Red Hat 8.x)?

The .so does not use the C++ standard library (except for ), but internally uses C++ exceptions. Its external API is C only, all exceptions are caught inside (incl. using "catch(...)" to be on the safe side).

The experience now is that despite versioning efforts in GLIBC a .so built with GCC 4.7.2 and loaded by the main program via dlopen does run on a system with libc.so.6 etc. of version 2.12, but not on a system with version 2.5, weird abort() and terminate() calls occur when throwing the exceptions.

The .so was compiled with "-fabi-version=2". No linker / loader errors occur on any platforms.

So my question is how to achieve this task of building such an .so which can run on older platforms? It must be possible.

Comment: My condolences for having to deal with LINUX/UNIX. I'm suffering the same fate. Avoid Linux/UNIX. Use a system (I'm not going to tell you the name), which is able (since 20 years) to deal with multiple different runtime libraries inside a single process and which does not suffer the problem of std:: always ending up as weak symbols (not being able to hide symbols from the std namespace, even if it is std::vector<yourNameSpace::yourClass>).

Answer (score 0):

On Linux `g++` links in `libstdc++` and `libgcc_s` to your executables and shared libraries.

I would try using `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++` to link these statically into your shared library. And then would check `ldd my.so` output to make sure your shared library does not link unwanted `.so`.